# How to call a function inside a success function in Sencha Touch?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a Controller with these functions:

```
onBtnBack: function(){
    Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem('vLogin');
},

onBtnSave: function (){
 Ext.Ajax.request({
     success: function(response) {
         Ext.Msg.alert('', 'OK', Ext.emptyFn);
         onBtnBack();
     }
 });
```

},

I'm trying to execute onBtnBack(); function inside success, but I'm getting this error:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: onBtnBack is not defined**.

tried to put `this.onBtnBack();` but it doesn't work either.

Does anyone know what cause this error?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't have a function called `onBtnBack` - that's what JS is telling you.

Comment: Without additional code to see how/where onBtnBack() is defined it's hard to give you any useful advice.

Comment: Sorry for that,  I made some corrections. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
onBtnSave: function (){
 var me = this;
 Ext.Ajax.request({
     success: function(response) {
         Ext.Msg.alert('', 'OK', Ext.emptyFn);
         me.onBtnBack();
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
onBtnSave: function() {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        success: function(response) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('', 'OK', Ext.emptyFn);
            this.onBtnBack();
        },
        scope: this
    });
}
```